# Adding tsconfig file to ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typescript

I have been going by this tutorial

> http://yizeng.me/2017/05/20/add-typescript-support-to-ruby-on-rails-a-quick-and-hacky-example/

And all working great.

Now tsconfig is looking like this

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outFile": "app/assets/javascripts/generated/welcome.js",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "noEmitOnError": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5"
  },
  "files": [
      "app/assets/javascripts/welcome.ts"
  ]
}
```

But as I see in `tsconfig` file I have `outfile` and `files`. How I can set all files with `.ts` extension in files. And How I can make it to compile not in one outfile?

**UPDATE**

I tried to write it like this

`"files": [
        "app/**/*.ts"
    ]`

But I get this error

> error TS6053: File '/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/falco-web/app/**/*.ts' not found.

File is under this path

`app/assets/javascripts/welcome.ts`

Comment: It accepts standard shell pass expansion `"files": [ "app/**/*.ts" ]`. Another question is unclear.

Comment: So it will include all files with `.ts` extensions?

About another question. As I understood `outfile` is used for generate js code from ts code? It's ok to make it like this?@mudasobwa

Comment: I tried to add pass like you said. But when I run ` rake assets:tsc` I have 
`error TS6053: File '/Users/admin/Documents/GitHub/falco-web/app/**/*.ts' not found.`

File path `app/javascripts/welcome.ts` @mudasobwa